# Scrape data in URL from 404 error-scrape

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape data from a webpage, however I get a 404 error for the URLs below. However, there is data from the 404 link that I need from within the browser. Here's the example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url <- "http://www.uscho.com/scoreboard/division-i-men/20172018/composite-schedule/"

link_list <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("td:nth-child(13) a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  {paste0("http://www.uscho.com", .)}
```

Now, for example, search the 200th example here (http://www.uscho.com/recaplink.php?gid=1_970_20172018) in your web browser. You'll get this:

[image]

I don't actually want the 404 Error, but in the address bar, there's a URL that -- after some manipulation -- I can use to get the actual webpage that I want (`"https://www.uscho.com/recaps/?p=171810970"`)

This URL, however, doesn't show up in R. Running `read_html(link_list[200])`, I only get a 404 error.

Any idea how I can get the URL from the browser within R?

Comment: If you have already found the pattern. You can apply the same pattern to other searches using search parameter `?p=****`

Comment: what do you mean? I'm still not sure what the exact pattern is to be honest

Comment: Oh, I thought you already knew the pattern. Have you tried tested on the pattern you found yet?

Comment: Yeah I've tried some things out to see if I could avoid asking this question, but there doesn't seem to be a simple pattern

Comment: It seems like some links are expired, changed or removed and not updated on that table. You can do your best to guess the actual link based on that website's structure. But I don't think there is an better way.

Comment: You know what's weird, there seems to be a pattern now. Yesterday, I didn't see any pattern. Weird. That may be the easiest way

Comment: And... nevermind. Not really a pattern that I can use

Answer (score 0):

To get the URL from the browser within R using `rvest` you can search for the meta data:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555460/scrape-data-in-url-from-404-error-scrape"
url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//meta[@property="og:url"]') %>%
  html_attr('content')
#[1] "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555460/scrape-data-in-url-from-404-error-scrape"
```

However, this will not suffice for your case. I think it would be better for you to use `RSelenium` to scrape the data dynamically. It might be slower, but it is most certainly a solution to your problem. You can check out [this tutorial](https://ropensci.org/tutorials/rselenium_tutorial/) on how to do so.

**EDIT:**
Not really experienced with `splashr`, but I do know that `RSelenium` is different from `rvest` because Selenium simulates whereas `rvest` is dependent on RESTful API's. It crashes when a 404 is received, where Selenium can just ignore by waiting using `setImplicitWaitTimeout()` so that the page redirects. You can then get the URL captured by using `remoteDriver$getCurrentUrl()`

Comment: thanks for the response. how would using `RSelenium` help though? I use `splashr` which is similar to `RSelenium`, but I'm still not sure how to capture the URL

Comment: Edited my answer or else it'd be a long comment